# Replace/Fill values in a (filtered) subset of a dataframe from another dataframe (differently indexed) based on a mutual column

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Struggling to figure out how to replace filtered(in this case blank) values of my main dataframe, with values from another dataframe *where I have a same column/key between them.*

**This is what I have:**

main_df on which I need to fill my blank potato `( == '')` values:

```
    date        banana      potato  avocado
33  2017-06-01  55ee4cbc    80660   b57c-2473556952a8
34  2017-06-01  391dc0f6            82ff-46de03510afc
35  2017-06-01  3a1f407f    54408   a3a6-d85429eef303
36  2017-06-01  3a1f407f    54408   858d-48082acc66ed
37  2017-06-01  5222ab45    80693   ba1f-dbd387748b71
38  2017-06-01  5222ab45    80693   b085-99d58875084a
39  2017-06-01  5222ab45    80693   a570-6d4c766ff7cf
40  2017-06-01  6939ced3            960c-a9ded8ed2f56
41  2017-06-01  2478913a    80610   9258-df6d26027d18
42  2017-06-01  2478913a    80610   8e53-a1d8d4e175b9
43  2017-06-01  2478913a    80610   b4b2-a9221895f8b5
```

banana_potato_matched_df to fill the blanks in main DF based on matching *banana* value (interested in *potato* indexes 0 and 3) :

```
    banana      potato
0   391dc0f6    80686
1   3a1f407f    54408
2   5222ab45    80693
3   6939ced3    55031
4   2478913a    80610
```

**Hoping to end up with this:** 
By preserving the same index, or if it resets the index to include all values from main dataframe

```
    date        banana      potato  avocado
33  2017-06-01  55ee4cbc    80660   b57c-2473556952a8
34  2017-06-01  391dc0f6    80686   82ff-46de03510afc
35  2017-06-01  3a1f407f    54408   a3a6-d85429eef303
36  2017-06-01  3a1f407f    54408   858d-48082acc66ed
37  2017-06-01  5222ab45    80693   ba1f-dbd387748b71
38  2017-06-01  5222ab45    80693   b085-99d58875084a
39  2017-06-01  5222ab45    80693   a570-6d4c766ff7cf
40  2017-06-01  6939ced3    55031   960c-a9ded8ed2f56
41  2017-06-01  2478913a    80610   9258-df6d26027d18
42  2017-06-01  2478913a    80610   8e53-a1d8d4e175b9
43  2017-06-01  2478913a    80610   b4b2-a9221895f8b5
```

**What I've tried**

If I merge it, then I end up with new frame which I am not sure how to assign back to the original one

```
pd.merge(linear_df[linear_df.potato== ''], banana_potato_matched_df, how='left', on='banana')

    date        banana      potato_x    potato_y    avocado
0   2017-06-01  55ee4cbc                NaN         b57c-2473556952a8
1   2017-06-01  391dc0f6                80686       82ff-46de03510afc
2   2017-06-01  3a1f407f                NaN         a3a6-d85429eef303
3   2017-06-01  3a1f407f                NaN         858d-48082acc66ed
4   2017-06-01  5222ab45                NaN         ba1f-dbd387748b71
5   2017-06-01  5222ab45                NaN         b085-99d58875084a
6   2017-06-01  5222ab45                NaN         a570-6d4c766ff7cf
7   2017-06-01  6939ced3                55031       960c-a9ded8ed2f56
8   2017-06-01  2478913a                80610       9258-df6d26027d18
9   2017-06-01  2478913a                80610       8e53-a1d8d4e175b9
10  2017-06-01  2478913a                80610       b4b2-a9221895f8b5
```

> Other way I think of is to split my main_df to 2 dataframes. One with
>   blank values (blank_main_df) and another with filled values
>   (filled_main_df). To merge blank_main_df with banana_potato_matched_df on banana key
>   and append to filled_main_df.  Is that the best way  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of merge you can simply convert the `banana_potato_matched_df` to dict and then `map` the values to `potato` in df . i.e

```
banana_dict = dict(zip(banana_potato_matched_df.banana, banana_potato_matched_df.potato))
```

banana_dict :

```
{'2478913a': 80610,
 '391dc0f6': 80686,
 '3a1f407f': 54408,
 '5222ab45': 80693,
 '6939ced3': 55031}
```

Map the values

```
df.loc[df.potato == '','potato'] = df.loc[df.potato == '','banana'].map(banana_dict)
```

Output :

```
          date    banana potato            avocado
0                                                 
33  2017-06-01  55ee4cbc  80660  b57c-2473556952a8
34  2017-06-01  391dc0f6  80686  82ff-46de03510afc
35  2017-06-01  3a1f407f  54408  a3a6-d85429eef303
36  2017-06-01  3a1f407f  54408  858d-48082acc66ed
37  2017-06-01  5222ab45  80693  ba1f-dbd387748b71
38  2017-06-01  5222ab45  80693  b085-99d58875084a
39  2017-06-01  5222ab45  80693  a570-6d4c766ff7cf
40  2017-06-01  6939ced3  55031  960c-a9ded8ed2f56
41  2017-06-01  2478913a  80610  9258-df6d26027d18
42  2017-06-01  2478913a  80610  8e53-a1d8d4e175b9
43  2017-06-01  2478913a  80610  b4b2-a9221895f8b5
```

Hope it helps

Comment: great answer Bharath, I was looking for something like this. Can you explain how map relates in this situation?

Comment: `map` will take the keys value from banana series one by one and then fetches the value from the dictionary based on that key.

Answer (score 1):

How about as such?

First make a data frame where the values are null:

```
combo = pd.merge(df[pd.isnull(df.potato)], subdf, how='left', on='banana', suffixes=('_',''))
```

Then let's drop the extra column:

```
combo.drop('potato_', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Finally lets concatenate back our data frame with the original one:

```
pd.concat([df[pd.notnull(df.potato)], combo], axis=0)
```

There is probably a way to do this using `fillna` but the solution is eluding me right now. I will edit for that if I think of it.

Comment: thanks @aws_apprentice I was thinking of this way, but it's so winded. Surely there must be other way. 
I was hoping for something as simple as this:
main_df.loc[main_df.banana == '','banana'] = banana_potato_matched_df.banana